# How do I use my own Hand-Drawn Image in TensorFlow Number Recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have some basic Python code to create a very basic neural network that classifies hand-drawn numbers from the MNIST dataset.

The network is working and I would like to make a prediction against a hand drawn image that is not part of the MNIST dataset.

**Here is my code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist # 28x28 images of handwritten digits (0-9)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(val_loss, val_acc)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**Below is where I can make predictions. I would like to change the code so that I can predict against my own hand-drawn image (labeled "test_image.jpg"):**

```
predictions = model.predict([x_test])

import numpy as np

print(np.argmax(predictions[0]))
```

Any ideas would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your model is trained on black and white images, you only have one channel and you need to convert your image to greyscale:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('test_image.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, (28,28))
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = np.reshape(img, [1,28,28])

predictions = model.predict(img)
print(np.argmax(predictions[0]))
```

Comment: hi @kluu - when trying to use imshow I get the following error. Any ideas? `TypeError: Invalid shape (10,) for image data`

Comment: oh, what are you trying to plot? If you want to display your processed image, it should be `plt.imshow(img[0,:,:])`.

Comment: hmm interesting - when showing the processed image, it is still in BGR color format (not greyscale). Any ideas, @kluu?

Comment: my bad, you might need to specify the colormap argument: `plt.imshow(img[0,:,:], cmap='gray')`.